# Setting width + height of svg inside svg

Tags: svg

I am making an svg file. The svg has an svg inside it. I tried to set the width and height of the inner svg, but the svg width and height stayed at 0. I found this out from the inspect panel.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <svg width="40" height="40" viewbox="30 30 40 40"></svg>
</svg>
```

This is what the code snippet above looks like with the inspect panel.
[image: 0x0 svg]
If I put an object inside, lets say, a 10x10 rectangle, it looks like this (snippet below).

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <svg width="40" height="40">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"></rect>
 </svg>
</svg>
```

The above snippet viewed from the inspect panel.
[image: bad svg]

From the inspect panel, you can see, I can't set the width, height, x, or y position of the svg using the width, height, or viewbox attributes. Is there any way I *can* set the width and height of the svg regardless of the svg's children?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by setting a width and height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the correct spelling: It's "view**B**ox" (camelCase).

But it's true when inspecting a nested `<svg>` in devtools the bounding box dimensions will be calculated based on the actual child elements.

However, all child elements will be positioned according to the `viewBox` - just as expected:

```css
svg{
  display:block;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<svg class="svgOuter" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <svg class="svgInner" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <circle cx="100%" cy="100%" r="25%" fill="green"/>
  </svg>
</svg>

<svg class="svgOuter" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <svg class="svgInner" x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <circle cx="0%" cy="0%" r="25%" fill="green"/>
    <circle cx="100%" cy="0%" r="25%" fill="green"/>
    <circle cx="100%" cy="100%" r="50%" fill="red"/>
  </svg>
</svg>
```